# Uploading a file in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permissions, upload

New wordpress user.

I am trying to upload a file in WordPress using the Media > Add New -- Option but when I click upload I get the following error:

```
The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads.
```

I have Wordpress 5.3.2 installed locally on my system using XAMPP.

I have tried almost all the methods mentioned in other posts, including changing the permissions in the terminal using

```
chmod 755 uploads
```

This has no change whatsoever.

> PS: I have created the uploads folder manually.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it can be a problem on the upload configuration in PHP. try to make an upload in pure PHP.

Comment: Try to change all sub-directories permission to 777 or 755. It will work. Only main directory permission will not be able to solve this issue...

Comment: Figured out the solution. Went to the root directory and gave the permissions. Thanks for the help guys.